# How to sort and group new notification - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have difficulties while I find it hard to group notifications based on notifications that have just entered. so the goal is that notifications that have just arrived can be seen at the top. for the new notification will be marked with 'NEW' and here I use the ListView to sort the data. This is a notification page for users when buying and selling and chatting. the point is how to set the right position and sort the data based on the new notification

```
Widget widget_purchase() {
return new Expanded(
  child: RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: () async {
      pagePurchase = 1;
      await getDataPurchase();
      pagePurchase = 2;
      return true;
    },
    child: LoadMore(
      isFinish: lastPurchase == 0,
      whenEmptyLoad: true,
      textBuilder: DefaultLoadMoreTextBuilder.english,
      onLoadMore: () async {
        await getDataPurchase();
        pagePurchase += 1;
        return true;
      },
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _purchase.length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return new Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 5, 0, 0),
            child: new GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context, '/purchase_page',
                  arguments: _purchase[index]['id']
                ).then((val) async {
                    pagePurchase = 1;
                    await getDataPurchase();
                    pagePurchase = 2;
                });
                idPurchase = _purchase[index]['id'];
                patchUpdatePurchase();
              },
              child: new Container(
                //height: 100,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: new Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 5, 0),
                      child: new FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                        placeholder: "",
                        height: 70,
                        width: 100,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        image: _purchase[index]['filePath'][0],
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Flexible(
                      child: new Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                        child: new Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Row(
                              children : <Widget>[
                                Flexible(
                                  child: new Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
                                    child: new Text(
                                      _purchase[index]['game_title'],
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      maxLines: 2,
                                      style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: selectedColor,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                _purchase[index]['isRead'] == false ? 
                                new Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                                  child: new Container(
                                    child: new Icon(
                                      Icons.fiber_new,
                                      color: selectedColor,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                                : new SizedBox.shrink(),
                              ],
                            ),
                            new Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: new Text(
                                _purchase[index]['product_type_name'],
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                              ),
                            ),
                            new Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
                                  child: new Text(
                                    'US\$',
                                    style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                new Flexible(
                                  child: new Text(
                                    " " + _purchase[index]['amount'].toString(),
                                    style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            new Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: new Text(
                                _purchase[index]['status'],
                                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
);}
```

[image: Here's the image]

Comment: Which property tells you that the data is new? Do you keep a timestamp of data or a status?

Comment: here's the code that show the message is read or not yet : _purchase[index]['isRead'] == false

Comment: So all you want is all new purchases to be positioned at the top. The rest to be lower than new purchases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want all new purchases to be positioned at the top. The rest to be lower than new purchases.

Before building the widget you can just sort the order of `_purchase` based on `isRead`. If `isRead` property is `false` give it a low sort order, making it show higher in an ascending order.

```
Widget widget_purchase() {
   _purchase.sort((a, b) => (b['isRead']? 1 : 0) - (a['isRead']? 1 : 0));

   //Your code....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a property for new notification. Ex: `status`:

```
purchases.sort((a, b) => a["status"].compareTo(b["status"])); // if list contains model: a.status
```

Just call above line after adding all values to `purchases` list and note that `List`'s [`sort()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/List/sort.html) doesnt return anything.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean. where should i put the code above?

Comment: My goal is how to group messages that read "NEW". while the data type is boolean

Comment: @Capt.America I have noted where to put that know. and read the comment too

Comment: @Capt.America According to your last update replace `status` with `isRead`